# How can I programmatically send a blank password?

Tags: linux, bash, svn

I have a shell script that checks out a subversion repo.  The connection asks for a password (I know it's an unnecessary layer since the password is blank), but how can I send a blank password to subversion?

```
#!/bin/sh

svn co svn://server/repo ~/Desktop/data
```

This then sends a password prompt to the terminal, is there a way to automatically respond in my script with a blank password?

Comment: @dannrob I read that thread, but they don't address handling a blank password.  I tried using empty quotes but that didn't work.  I still get prompted when using `--password ""`

Comment: Have you tried redirecting a file consisting just of newlines into it? So, create a text file which is just blank lines and then run your command like svn co svn://server/repo ~/Desktop/data < blanklines.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying password using the following option:

`--password ''`

Comment: I lied, this worked.  I tried it a long time ago and this did not resolve my issue.  I guess maybe I put the switch in the wrong place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't recommend doing it like that, but a more generic way would be the use of ***expect***:

[How to give password in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358509/how-to-give-password-in-shell-script)